# Selenium webdriver.get() method doesnt always work

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
link = "https://www.google.com"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % str(xxx))
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
time.sleep(3)
chrome.get(link)
print("po get")
time.sleep(1)
chrome.get(link)
time.sleep(15)
```

Hello, I have a problem with selenium for a long time and I would like to find a way how to fix it
The problem is that almost everytime I run a script that's opening selenium / even when I use it like
for a test such as :

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome = webdriver.Chrome()
chrome.get(https://www.google.com)
```

It still sometimes doesn't get the website, I thought it's because of how slow selenium opens but even after its nicely open it doesn't get the value, sadly it just gets stuck on an empty browser that had data in an url window... any idea what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Please make sure your **Chrome/Selenium/ChromeDriver** are all on recommended builds. you can check which version of ChromeDriver is supported on your version of chrome [HERE](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads). I have seen this issue when not on ***up to date*** combinations.

Comment: As @PixelEinstein mentioned update the question with you binary version information and _error stack trace_

Comment: Yes I have downloaded latest release, I have been even trying an older realeases to check if its some kind of a bug in the version, but no, its not a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after a few hours I decided to give it a little try and change ( "" ) to ( ' ' ) and as I can see it works :D I dont know why it has a problem with string ""

here is edited line of my code :

```
chrome.get('https://www.google.com')
```

> ( I ve tried it with proxies with loop that was starting the webdriver
>   100 times , and everytime after i've changed it, it passed )

Comment: There is no difference between using `''` or `""` when quoting strings in Python. I think there must be something else going on here.

Comment: Glad you're now up and running though!

Comment: @PixelEinstein I know there is no difference, i just found out that before it wasnt doing this kind of stuff , so I looked up what I was doing before and now, and the only difference were quotes ... and I left it to run for a few hours and no error ... so for me it was a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `driver.navigate.to("");`

Also as I see, You might missing String Double Quotes " " here,  `chrome.get(https://www.google.com)`

Comment: you can see on a first line that a string quotes are there , but i am going to try that driver.navige.to() function ^.^ thanks for that one

Answer (score 0):

I think it's too late for answer, but I want to answer anyway. You may have already solved problem, but if it doesn't work check this out:

1. Different links navigate you same site or etc. It is not a code error but I want to say that this could cause of `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element`
2. You logged a site and if you want to go back login screen, you should log out of your account, otherwise the site will automatically navigate to the home screen because you already logged in.

That's all I wanted to say.